# How to control CANoe with Python script?

Tags: python, canoe

I am working with Vectoe CANoe version 8.5. I have written the CAPL script to send messages. Now I want to write a python script which when executed, starts the execution in CANoe. How to achieve this.

Comment: You cannot control CANoe environment without its API library. You must investigate the API lib, which is in C++ or .NET in the Help section of CANoe, and create the API program which then can launch through a python script if you wish.

Comment: CAnoe withh support Python interaction.  in python install canoe library and you able to send messages

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by using the COM interface to CANoe.
You can use COM interfaces also from python.

CANoe's COM interface is well documented. Just take a look into the user documentation.

For calling COM from python, the most common way is using the [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) library.

Answer (score 1):

You can get sample COM automation via Python `.py` file in (`C:\Users\Public\Documents\Vector\CANoe\Sample Configurations 15.1.1\Programming\Python\`) this CANoe install directory.

[See image for config location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knfJB.png)

Note: Avoid using third party library to control CANoe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python Library Python-CANoe Available to do this.

path to the library https://pypi.org/project/Python-CANoe/

Comment: It is better to use CANoe's help document and sample programs to create an application rather than to use a third party library.